# Simplest LSTM with attention (Encoder-Decoder architecture) using Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model, encoder-decoder

please, help me understand how to write LSTM (RNN) with attention using Encoder-Decoder architecture. I've watched a lot of videos on YouTube, read some articles on towardsdatascience.com and so on but those examples are very complex for me. I need the **most simple example** of RNN that can do what I said before.

Anyway, I did some attempts to write it myself (and it works!) *but the loss is big all the time and it is almost not changing*. I can explain you how I think it should work (and I'm going to describe every step I did in my code) but please can you correct me (I mean say, where my mistakes were) and **make from my code** (if it possible) the workable LSTM  with attention with Encoder-Decoder architecture. I would be so happy to get this important knowledge for me. Let's go!

Firstly, here is the full code:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch
import numpy as np

class Encoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(1, 1, 1, batch_first=True)

  def forward(self, input):
    output, hidden_state = self.lstm(input)
    #print('DATA:', self.lstm.weight_hh_l0[0])
    return output

class Decoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(10, 1, 1, batch_first=True)
    self.linear = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(10, 10) for i in range(10)])
    self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=0)

  def forward(self, input):
    input = input.view(1, 10)
    initial_input = input.clone()
    for i in range(10):
      if i == 0:
        input = self.linear[i](input)
        #print(input)
      else:
        input = torch.cat((input, self.linear[i](initial_input)), 0)
        #print(input)
    input = input.view(-1, 10, 10)
    output, hidden_state = self.lstm(input)
    output = output.view(1, 10)
    return output

class RNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(RNN, self).__init__()

    self.encoder = Encoder()
    self.decoder = Decoder()
    print(self.encoder)
    print(self.decoder)

    self.loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    self.encoder_optimizer = optim.Adagrad(self.encoder.parameters(), lr=0.006)
    self.decoder_optimizer = optim.Adagrad(self.decoder.parameters(), lr=0.006)


  def train(self, input, target, test):

    # Encoder
    output_encoder = self.encoder(input)

    # Decoder
    output_decoder = self.decoder(output_encoder)

    if test:
      print(np.argmax(torch.nn.functional.softmax(output_decoder).detach().numpy().flatten()))

    self.encoder_optimizer.zero_grad()
    self.decoder_optimizer.zero_grad()

    loss = self.loss(output_decoder, target)
    print(loss)
    
    loss.backward()

    self.encoder_optimizer.step()
    self.decoder_optimizer.step()
    

    return 0

def main():
  rnn = RNN()

  input = [[10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3], [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4], [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5], [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6], [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7], [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8], [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9], [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10]]
  labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

  
  labels = torch.tensor(labels).type(dtype=torch.long)

  losses = []
  for epoch in range(100):
    input_copy = input[epoch % 10]
    labels_copy = [labels[epoch % 10]]
    labels_copy = torch.tensor(labels_copy).type(dtype=torch.long)
    input_copy = torch.tensor(input_copy).float().requires_grad_(True).view(1, 10, 1)
    rnn.train(input_copy, labels_copy, False)
  
  rnn.train(input_copy, labels_copy, True)

main()
```

Secondly, here is the picture I've made to help you understand what I did:

[click here to see image][1]

Also, I should say that this LSTM **has no any real meaning**, I just want to know how to write such type of RNN.

Let's dive into the code closer (**READ COMMENTS, PLEASE**), here is Encoder:

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(1, 1, 1, batch_first=True) #input is like [[1], [2], ..., [10]], also, I'm planning to get WHOLE output from this nn.LSTM (not the last state), I mean the variable 'output' down below

  def forward(self, input):
    output, hidden_state = self.lstm(input) # just implement nn.LSTM
    #print('DATA:', self.lstm.weight_hh_l0[0])
    return output
```

Here is Decoder (the most complex part for me):

```
class Decoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(10, 1, 1, batch_first=True) #initialize RNN for the decoder
    self.linear = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(10, 10) for i in range(10)]) #generating linear layer in order to kind of apply sub neural network that will somehow predict weights for important 'words' in our 'sentence' and I decided that those 10 linear layers (they were generated with different weights) should be applied to output from Encoder and each this linear layer should produce the 'input word' for the Decoder's LSTM (you can see what I said in the picture)
    self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=0)

  def forward(self, input): #doing what I said before
    input = input.view(1, 10)
    initial_input = input.clone()
    for i in range(10):
      if i == 0:
        input = self.linear[i](input)
        #print(input)
      else:
        input = torch.cat((input, self.linear[i](initial_input)), 0) #merge all outputs from linear layers in one tensor, so, we've made the input 'sentence' for our Decoder's LSTM
        #print(input)
    input = input.view(-1, 10, 10)
    output, hidden_state = self.lstm(input)
    output = output.view(1, 10)
    return output
```

In the class called 'RNN' we just initialize our Encoder and Decoder and we do the standart things for every simple RNN (anyway, I'm not sure whether I'm implementing all of them in a right order because now I have kind of two RNNs in one program (if it would be only one RNN, I'm sure that I'm doing everything right)).

Well, here are the rersults (this is the loss):

```
tensor(2.4289, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3605, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4271, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4054, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4332, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2394, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2026, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.0889, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3166, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3591, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3845, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3353, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4073, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3933, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4244, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2370, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2015, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.0889, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3139, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3567, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3785, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3313, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4027, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3904, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4217, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2371, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2024, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.0907, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3134, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3556, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3751, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3290, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3998, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3885, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4197, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2374, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2034, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.0925, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3135, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3549, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3727, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3274, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3975, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3870, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4181, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2376, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2043, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.0942, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3136, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3545, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3709, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3261, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3956, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3857, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4168, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2378, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2052, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.0957, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3139, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3541, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3693, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3250, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3940, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3846, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4155, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2380, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2060, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.0972, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3141, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3539, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3679, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3240, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3925, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3836, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4144, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2382, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2068, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.0985, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3144, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3537, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3667, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3232, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3912, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3828, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4134, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2384, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2075, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.0998, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3147, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3535, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3656, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3224, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3900, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3819, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.4125, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2386, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.2082, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.1009, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3150, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
tensor(2.3534, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
```

Well, can you help me? This RNN should predict which sequence (like [10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]) belongs to what class.

**Please, if it's possible, change my code in order to I could look at workable example and improve my understanding**. I also know that LSTM with attention is needed to work with very big "sequence_length' but I just want to understand the **concept** of suce architecture. Or can you write me new **simplest** example? Well, any help will be appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2V0S.jpg

Comment: Have you seen the tutorial on PyTorch's website? It is quite good.

Comment: @shahensha, yes, but I need the most simplest example for *classification task with attention*. PyTorch's website provides Encoder-Decoder architecture that won't be useful in my case. Can you help me? For example, can you write me code that will solve the task that I wrote before? Maybe it would be better to use convolutional layers for this task. I'm still looking for any help because I'm not a pro in machine learning but I really want to figure out how it works. If you can, just help me with basic example.

Comment: Have you come across any article/paper which does classification with attention? IMHO, you do not need encoder-decoder+attention to do classification. The simplest thing that you can do here is just have an encoder which classifies every input token into a label. Attention with enc-dec would be needed in general seq2seq networks where len(input) != len(output).

Comment: @shahensha, firstly, yes, I've read some articles but most of them are too complex for me. Also, I understood that I don't need Encoder-Decoder for classification task. But how to implement attention to the (let's say, I have only Encoder) Encoder's output? I'm going to use these articles:

https://towardsdatascience.com/illustrated-self-attention-2d627e33b20a

https://medium.com/heuritech/attention-mechanism-5aba9a2d4727

But in order to be more confident that I'm doing everything right I would like to see on some truthful code :)

Comment: I see. Both the articles that you have linked actually talk about self attention. And if you were to use only encoder and use self attention, your best bet is to work with Transformers instead of RNNs or LSTMs. https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html is a good place to start. Let me know if this doesn't help.